# How can I chomp every line in an array at once?

Tags: ruby, arrays, chomp

In the interest of writing cleaner code...

```
IO.popen("Generate a list of files").readlines.each{ |line|
   chomped_line = line.chomp
   # ...
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
IO.popen("Generate a list of files").readlines.map(&:chomp)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
# Example 1
File.readlines("file.txt").each{|line| line.chomp!}

# Example 2
File.readlines("file.txt").map(&:chomp)

# Example 3
File.open("file.txt", "r"){|file| file.readlines.collect{|line| line.chomp}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IO.read("something").split($/)
```

$/ is the separator string. IO.read closes the file after reading.

Comment: Just a note that `$/` matches `\n` newlines strictly while chomp handles `\r\n` as well. If you know that you will only ever have `\n` newlines this solution is _much_ faster than the map/chomp option.

Answer (score 1):

I would make it faster and consuming less memory:

1. use "each_line" rather than "readlines.each". Why read the whole output at once?
2. use "chomp!" (exclamation mark) to change the string in-place.

Then it is:

```
IO.popen( "generate_lines").each_line { |line|
    line.chomp!
    do_something_with line
}
```